# Setting context-parameters programatically when using vaadin-cdi

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I annotated my UIs with @CDIUI and dont use web.xml for the binding. But how can I set context-parameters like debugMode, heartbeatIntervall, closeIdleSessions ... ? Is there a way to annotated those features or pass them inside the UI instance? Or do I have to provide a web.xml anyway? What about System.getProperty (the JBoss property handling)? Thanks for any clue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to implement your own `DeploymentConfiguration` in the following way:

```
public class ExampleUI extends UI {
    private class ExampleConfiguration implements DeploymentConfiguration {
        @Override
        public int getHeartbeatInterval() {
            return 30;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCloseIdleSessions() {
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        getSession().setConfiguration(new ExampleConfiguration());
        ...
    }
}
```

Then you can get context parameters outside `ExampleUI` class in a standard way:

```
VaadinSession.getCurrent().getConfiguration().getHeartbeatInterval();
VaadinSession.getCurrent().getConfiguration().isCloseIdleSessions();
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

While the solution proposed by wypieprz works as far as manually retrieving context parameters in your application, it doesn't actually work all the way.

In particular the `setConfiguration()` happens too late for Vaadin to actually use the the configured heartbeat interval etc.
Below is a way I got it to work. Basically it's the solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17163577/getting-rid-of-web-xml-in-vaadin-7-with-vaadinservlet) but with an additional `@WebInitParam` to get CDI to bootstrap properly again in the presence of an inline servlet configuration.

```
@WebServlet(value = { "/*", "/VAADIN/*"
            initParams = {
                @WebInitParam(name = Constants.SERVLET_PARAMETER_UI_PROVIDER, value = "com.vaadin.cdi.CDIUIProvider")
            })
@VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false,
                            ui = MyVaadinUI.class,
                            closeIdleSessions = true,
                            heartbeatInterval = 10)
public static class Servlet extends VaadinServlet
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, those parameters could be set in a properties file

```
vaadin.servlet.productionMode=true
vaadin.servlet.heartbeatInterval=55
```