# Getting rid of web.xml in Vaadin 7 with VaadinServlet

Tags: java, vaadin, web.xml, vaadin7, servlet-3.0

I'm new to Java and Vaadin. A basic Vaadin project is using `web.xml` for all the mappings. If I want to use the `@WebServlet` annotation I need to create an inner class which somewhere inherits from `HttpServlet`.

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class VaadinplaygroundUI extends UI {

    @WebServlet(urlPatterns="/Helo")
    public static class Servlet extends VaadinServlet {

    }

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
```

I know, I'm missing some overwritten methods in the inner class `Servlet` to get it working, but I don't know which. There are many examples in the internet for Vaadin 6.x where the inner class extends `AbstractApplicationServlet`.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's for 7.x:

```
public class MyUI extends UI {

    @WebServlet(value = "/*", asyncSupported = true, initParams = {
            @WebInitParam(name = "ui", value = "com.example.MyUI"),
            @WebInitParam(name = "productionMode", value = "false") })
    public static class Servlet extends VaadinServlet {
    }

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        ..
    }
}
```

And for 7.1 and newer:

```
public class MyUI extends UI {

    @WebServlet(value = "/*", asyncSupported = true)
    @VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = MyUI.class)
    public static class Servlet extends VaadinServlet {
    }

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        ..
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't there any way to avoid having this inner static class and instead annotate the request mapping directly on the UI class? Thanks in advance

Comment: @HenriKerola What is the use of the inner static class?