# Setting Vaadin session-timeout parameter

Tags: session-timeout, vaadin7

I am using Vaadin 7.1.7 and I can't figure out how to set `session-timeout` 
parameter (to, say, 1min).

As far as I can tell, Vaadin 7.x.x does not produce `web.xml`, it uses `@VaadinServletConfiguration` annotation but there doesn't seem to be a `session-timeout` parameter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting rid of web.xml in Vaadin 7 with VaadinServlet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17163577/getting-rid-of-web-xml-in-vaadin-7-with-vaadinservlet)

Answer (score 7):

As far as I know there are 2 ways to set session-timeout in Vaadin 7.

In the web.xml:

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>1</session-timeout> <!-- 1 minute -->
</session-config>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.xyz.web.MyServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <description>My Main Page</description>
        <param-name>UI</param-name>
        <param-value>com.xyz.web.MyUI</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <description>Enable Session Timeout (heartbeat can't keep alive)</description>
        <param-name>closeIdleSessions</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Or we can set it programmatically (current session only):

```
VaadinSession.getCurrent().getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(60); // 1 minute
```

It seems the servlet 3.0 annotations do not help: [link](http://www.baeldung.com/servlet-session-timeout)

More help here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960764/how-to-set-session-timeout-dynamically-in-java-web-applications)