# Enabling server-push for a Spring Boot powered Vaadin application does not work

Tags: tomcat, servlets, spring-boot, vaadin7, server-push

In our current project we want to use server-push in a Spring Boot powered Vaadin application.

We followed the instructions from the wiki article https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/advanced.push.html (added vaadin-push dependency to pom.xml, added @Push annotation to out UI class, did not set async-supported in the web.xml file because it does not exist in this case) and got the following error messages:

```
2014-06-17 14:32:43,340 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] WARN  org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - SessionSupport error. Make sure you define org.atmosphere.cpr.SessionSupport as a listener in web.xml instead
2014-06-17 14:32:44,981 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] WARN  org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAsyncSupportResolver - Found multiple containers, please specify which one to use: org.atmosphere.container.Tomcat7CometSupport, org.atmosphere.container.TomcatCometSupport,  until you do, Atmosphere will use:class org.atmosphere.container.Tomcat7CometSupport
2014-06-17 14:32:45,001 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] WARN  org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Failed using comet support: org.atmosphere.container.Tomcat7CometSupport, error: Tomcat failed to detect this is a Comet application because context.xml is missing or the Http11NioProtocol Connector is not enabled.You must use the atmosphere-native-runtime dependency in order to use native Comet Support
If that's not the case, you can also remove META-INF/context.xml and WEB-INF/lib/atmosphere-compat-tomcat7.jar Is the NIO or APR Connector enabled?
2014-06-17 14:32:45,005 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] ERROR org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - If you have more than one Connector enabled, make sure they both use the same protocol, e.g NIO/APR or HTTP for all. If not, org.atmosphere.container.BlockingIOCometSupport will be used and cannot be changed.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Tomcat failed to detect this is a Comet application because context.xml is missing or the Http11NioProtocol Connector is not enabled.You must use the atmosphere-native-runtime dependency in order to use native Comet Support
If that's not the case, you can also remove META-INF/context.xml and WEB-INF/lib/atmosphere-compat-tomcat7.jar
    at org.atmosphere.container.Tomcat7CometSupport.<clinit>(Tomcat7CometSupport.java:56) ~[atmosphere-runtime-2.1.2.vaadin2.jar:2.1.2.vaadin2]
    (...)
2014-06-17 14:32:45,006 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] WARN  org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Using org.atmosphere.container.BlockingIOCometSupport

2014-06-17 14:32:58,684 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR com.vaadin.server.DefaultErrorHandler - 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot suspend a response longer than the session timeout. Increase the value of session-timeout in web.xml
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereResourceImpl.suspend(AtmosphereResourceImpl.java:314) ~[atmosphere-runtime-2.1.2.vaadin2.jar:2.1.2.vaadin2]
    (...)
```

After reading the stackoverflow thread [Getting rid of web.xml in Vaadin 7 with VaadinServlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17163577/getting-rid-of-web-xml-in-vaadin-7-with-vaadinservlet) we added a static servlet to our UI class

```
@WebServlet(asyncSupported = true)
public static class Servlet extends VaadinServlet {
}
```

and got the same error messages:

```
2014-06-17 14:33:52,928 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] WARN  org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - SessionSupport error. Make sure you define org.atmosphere.cpr.SessionSupport as a listener in web.xml instead
2014-06-17 14:33:54,557 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] WARN  org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAsyncSupportResolver - Found multiple containers, please specify which one to use: org.atmosphere.container.Tomcat7CometSupport, org.atmosphere.container.TomcatCometSupport,  until you do, Atmosphere will use:class org.atmosphere.container.Tomcat7CometSupport
2014-06-17 14:33:54,577 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] WARN  org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Failed using comet support: org.atmosphere.container.Tomcat7CometSupport, error: Tomcat failed to detect this is a Comet application because context.xml is missing or the Http11NioProtocol Connector is not enabled.You must use the atmosphere-native-runtime dependency in order to use native Comet Support
If that's not the case, you can also remove META-INF/context.xml and WEB-INF/lib/atmosphere-compat-tomcat7.jar Is the NIO or APR Connector enabled?
2014-06-17 14:33:54,581 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - If you have more than one Connector enabled, make sure they both use the same protocol, e.g NIO/APR or HTTP for all. If not, org.atmosphere.container.BlockingIOCometSupport will be used and cannot be changed.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Tomcat failed to detect this is a Comet application because context.xml is missing or the Http11NioProtocol Connector is not enabled.You must use the atmosphere-native-runtime dependency in order to use native Comet Support
If that's not the case, you can also remove META-INF/context.xml and WEB-INF/lib/atmosphere-compat-tomcat7.jar
    at org.atmosphere.container.Tomcat7CometSupport.<clinit>(Tomcat7CometSupport.java:56) ~[atmosphere-runtime-2.1.2.vaadin2.jar:2.1.2.vaadin2]
   (...)
2014-06-17 14:33:54,582 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] WARN  org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Using org.atmosphere.container.BlockingIOCometSupport

2014-06-17 14:34:07,338 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] ERROR com.vaadin.server.DefaultErrorHandler - 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot suspend a response longer than the session timeout. Increase the value of session-timeout in web.xml
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereResourceImpl.suspend(AtmosphereResourceImpl.java:314) ~[atmosphere-runtime-2.1.2.vaadin2.jar:2.1.2.vaadin2]
    (...)
```

Adding a parameter for the session timeout did not change anything, too:

```
@WebServlet(asyncSupported = true, initParams = { @WebInitParam(name = "session-timeout", value = "120") })
public static class Servlet extends VaadinServlet {
}

2014-06-17 14:36:18,636 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] WARN  org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - SessionSupport error. Make sure you define org.atmosphere.cpr.SessionSupport as a listener in web.xml instead
2014-06-17 14:36:20,284 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] WARN  org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAsyncSupportResolver - Found multiple containers, please specify which one to use: org.atmosphere.container.Tomcat7CometSupport, org.atmosphere.container.TomcatCometSupport,  until you do, Atmosphere will use:class org.atmosphere.container.Tomcat7CometSupport
2014-06-17 14:36:20,303 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] WARN  org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Failed using comet support: org.atmosphere.container.Tomcat7CometSupport, error: Tomcat failed to detect this is a Comet application because context.xml is missing or the Http11NioProtocol Connector is not enabled.You must use the atmosphere-native-runtime dependency in order to use native Comet Support
If that's not the case, you can also remove META-INF/context.xml and WEB-INF/lib/atmosphere-compat-tomcat7.jar Is the NIO or APR Connector enabled?
2014-06-17 14:36:20,307 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - If you have more than one Connector enabled, make sure they both use the same protocol, e.g NIO/APR or HTTP for all. If not, org.atmosphere.container.BlockingIOCometSupport will be used and cannot be changed.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Tomcat failed to detect this is a Comet application because context.xml is missing or the Http11NioProtocol Connector is not enabled.You must use the atmosphere-native-runtime dependency in order to use native Comet Support
If that's not the case, you can also remove META-INF/context.xml and WEB-INF/lib/atmosphere-compat-tomcat7.jar
    at org.atmosphere.container.Tomcat7CometSupport.<clinit>(Tomcat7CometSupport.java:56) ~[atmosphere-runtime-2.1.2.vaadin2.jar:2.1.2.vaadin2]
    (...)
2014-06-17 14:36:20,308 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] WARN  org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - Using org.atmosphere.container.BlockingIOCometSupport

2014-06-17 14:36:44,341 [http-nio-8080-exec-9] ERROR com.vaadin.server.DefaultErrorHandler - 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot suspend a response longer than the session timeout. Increase the value of session-timeout in web.xml
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereResourceImpl.suspend(AtmosphereResourceImpl.java:314) ~[atmosphere-runtime-2.1.2.vaadin2.jar:2.1.2.vaadin2]
    (...)
```

Do you have any ideas for a solution?

Comment: As this post is a year old: Do you still have the problem? I am using vaadin-spring-boot with @Push without any problems

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Spring + Vaadin works only if you haven't set WEBSOCKET as transport mode. Try to change it to long polling or streaming:

```
@Push(transport = Transport.LONG_POLLING)
```

Personally, I still use old xml configuration for web application. Here is part of the push configuration for Vaadin 7.

```
 <!-- Vaadin context -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ISM Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.vaadin.spring.servlet.SpringAwareVaadinServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>closeIdleSessions</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:ism-web.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <!-- Vaadin 7.1 @Push -->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.atmosphere.useWebSocketAndServlet3</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>
```

Comment: The problem is that we use Spring Boot and so there is no web.xml file by default (it would be easy to just create the web.xml file but I don't know how to ensure that it is used). Adding @Push(transport = Transport.LONG_POLLING) respectively @Push(transport = Transport.STREAMING) to the UI class did not change anything, unfortunately. I also added "@WebInitParam(name = "org.atmosphere.useWebSocketAndServlet3", value = "true")" to the @WebServlet annotation. No success, too. :-(

Comment: Take a look into vaadin4spring sources at: https://github.com/peholmst/vaadin4spring

Vaadin4spring is upcomming official addon for Vaadin. I'm curious why you use spring boot? You can do all these things without spring boot.

Comment: At the end, as far I remember annotation config must be declared in servlet class that extends VaadinServlet.

Comment: Our project already contains vaadin4spring (org.vaadin.spring - spring-boot-vaadin). I guess I should have mentioned that. I know that Spring Boot is not needed for server-push. We use it to start an embedded Tomcat server which hosts our application.

Comment: How do I have to interpret your 2nd comment? As you can see in my question, I already experimented with an inline servlet that extends VaadinServlet.

Answer (score 0):

After watching the following Vaadin webinars, I switched from server-push to polling which solved my problem:

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GOKX-bGmi0k
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZUshNi_4Gqc

The following wiki describes how to use polling:

https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Using+polling